# Heroku run rake db:migrate creates different db than schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, database-schema

I am attempting to migrate my app to Heroku on the MySQL database ClearDb. Upon running `heroku rake db:migrate` the result in MySQL workbench does not match the `schema.rb` at all, therefore creating problems when attempting to launch and view the deployed app.

Is it possible to "reset" the heroku migrations commands so that it will actually match the apps `schema.rb` file?

The result of running `heroku rake db:migrate`:

[image]

The `schema.rb` file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2****************) do

  create_table "business_users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.boolean  "admin",           default: false, null: false
    t.string   "phoneNum"
    t.integer  "zipCode"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "website"
    t.string   "addinfo"
    t.integer  "removed",         default: 0,     null: false
  end

  add_index "business_users", ["city"], name: "index_business_users_on_city", using: :btree
  add_index "business_users", ["email"], name: "index_business_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "business_users", ["remember_token"], name: "index_business_users_on_remember_token", using: :btree
  add_index "business_users", ["state"], name: "index_business_users_on_state", using: :btree
  add_index "business_users", ["zipCode"], name: "index_business_users_on_zipCode", using: :btree

  create_table "campaign_categories", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "campaign_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "campaign_category_metro_bids", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "campaign_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "metro_id"
    t.float    "average_bid_price"
    t.float    "average_placement"
    t.integer  "number_times_user_pulled"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.float    "set_max_bid"
  end

  add_index "campaign_category_metro_bids", ["average_bid_price"], name: "index_campaign_category_metro_bids_on_average_bid_price", using: :btree
  add_index "campaign_category_metro_bids", ["campaign_id"], name: "index_campaign_category_metro_bids_on_campaign_id", using: :btree
  add_index "campaign_category_metro_bids", ["set_max_bid"], name: "index_campaign_category_metro_bids_on_set_max_bid", using: :btree

  create_table "campaign_locations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "campaign_id", null: false
    t.integer  "location_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "campaign_metros", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "campaign_id"
    t.integer  "metro_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "campaign_metros", ["campaign_id"], name: "index_campaign_metros_on_campaign_id", using: :btree
  add_index "campaign_metros", ["metro_id"], name: "index_campaign_metros_on_metro_id", using: :btree

  create_table "campaigns", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "restaurant_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.float    "bid_price"
    t.float    "budget"
    t.string   "ad_caption"
    t.string   "ad_details"
    t.boolean  "mobile_order",          default: false
    t.boolean  "call_order",            default: false
    t.string   "mobile_site",           default: "0"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "ad_details_fine_print"
    t.boolean  "monday",                default: false
    t.boolean  "tuesday",               default: false
    t.boolean  "wednesday",             default: false
    t.boolean  "thursday",              default: false
    t.boolean  "friday",                default: false
    t.boolean  "saturday",              default: false
    t.boolean  "sunday",                default: false
    t.boolean  "breakfast",             default: false
    t.boolean  "lunch",                 default: false
    t.boolean  "dinner",                default: false
    t.integer  "texts",                 default: 0
    t.integer  "clicks",                default: 0
    t.string   "start_dt"
    t.string   "end_dt"
    t.integer  "get_there",             default: 0
    t.integer  "restaurant_favorited",  default: 0
    t.integer  "user_saves",            default: 0
    t.boolean  "is_active",             default: false
    t.boolean  "removed",               default: false, null: false
  end

  add_index "campaigns", ["restaurant_id"], name: "index_campaigns_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "active",     default: true, null: false
  end

  create_table "cities", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.integer  "state_id"
    t.string   "city_whole"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "active",     default: 1, null: false
  end

  create_table "locations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "store_number"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "state"
    t.integer  "zip"
    t.string   "sit_down"
    t.string   "drive_through"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "city_name"
    t.integer  "restaurant_id"
    t.integer  "city_id"
    t.integer  "user_set_active", default: 1,     null: false
    t.boolean  "removed",         default: false, null: false
  end

  add_index "locations", ["city_name"], name: "index_locations_on_city", using: :btree
  add_index "locations", ["latitude"], name: "index_locations_on_latitude", using: :btree
  add_index "locations", ["longitude"], name: "index_locations_on_longitude", using: :btree
  add_index "locations", ["restaurant_id"], name: "index_locations_on_user_id", using: :btree
  add_index "locations", ["state"], name: "index_locations_on_state", using: :btree
  add_index "locations", ["store_number"], name: "index_locations_on_store_number", using: :btree

  create_table "metros", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
  end

  add_index "metros", ["latitude"], name: "index_metros_on_latitude", using: :btree
  add_index "metros", ["longitude"], name: "index_metros_on_longitude", using: :btree

  create_table "restaurant_menus", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "restaurant_id"
    t.string   "item_name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "iamge"
    t.integer  "calories"
    t.float    "price"
    t.integer  "period"
    t.integer  "type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "restaurants", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "business_user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "removed",          default: false, null: false
  end

  create_table "states", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the schema is better than the migrations, you can use `rake db:schema:load` instead. But TBH I'd figure out why the two have diverged... it sounds a bit dangerous.

Comment: I was using the migrations at first, then moved my app the MySQL with PHPMyAdmin and used PHPMyAdmin instead of migrations. Therefore they are out of sync. Is there a definite way to 'sync' them?

Comment: add the missing migrations (that consist of whatever you did manually in PHPMyAdmin)... also for a Rails site - you should never do anything that changes the database without doing it via migrations... or else you end up in this state ;)

Comment: I have the `schema.rb`, can I possibly create a new app, save all the other files to that new app, and run a big migration with all the schema.rb contents to get back into sync?

Comment: I would not advise that - because it's the schema that is wrong. The migrations should always be correct and get you to a working version of your app. I'd look at the differences between the schema locally and the schema for a new app - and just create migrations that make the changes to match,

Comment: Can I erase specific migrations from existence? For example, running heroku run rake db:migrate shows the entry in the terminal:      `Migrating to CreateActiveCampaignDows (20131211034850)
==  CreateActiveCampaignDows: migrating =======================================
-- create_table(:active_campaign_dows)
   -> 0.0018s
==  CreateActiveCampaignDows: migrated (0.0019s) ==============================`     When I never explicitly created a migration with the actions shown

Comment: it's a truth universally acknowledged that fiddling with past migrations is a Bad Idea... Add new ones, don't remove/adjust old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all migration files. Then prepare one big migration with dump of your current database structure - you can use `execute` method to do this. Next run your tests and check if app is working with database created from this migration. If everything works, copy your data without schema_migrations table. Overwriting this table would break your migrations again.

This is the simplest solution (if you have made many changes), but it would be better to add missing migrations and import dump only with data, without database structure.